# execute a script on each page java-ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, multilingual

I'm trying to build a multilang website and for that I have to identify the user lang

The script is ok but I don't know how to execute my script on all my pages.

I have two ideas but I think there is a better solution.

1) execute my script in my tag file which is my page template and used in all my pages.

2) extends all my classes from a galbal class which execute the script in the constructor and call super in all child classes

As you can see my solutions are bads

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find the solution, I use filters

This is a sample to explain

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

@WebFilter(filterName="Main")
public class ExempleFilter implements Filter {
    public void init( FilterConfig config ) throws ServletException {
        // ...
    }

    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
        // ...
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

all you filter code goes in doFIlter and chain.doFilter(request, response); load your servlet

to finish you must add your filter to you router manager(web.xml)

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Main</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you please expalnd on this answer?  If other users have the same problem, a detailed answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One common solution for this problem is more like your option 2.

At the end of the constructor in the parent class call a new method `init()`. And in the child use `init()` instead of the constructor

Comment: thanks but I can't accès to HttpServletRequest request in the init or construct and I need this to use my cookie and sessions